# Given $\triangle ABC$ can we construct point $O$ such that $AO\times BC=BO\times AC=CO\times AB$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

Given a $\triangle ABC$, is it possible to construct, with compass and straightedge, a point $O$ such that
$$AO\cdot BC=BO\cdot AC=CO\cdot AB$$
Does that point exist?

Comment: When you say "construct", do you mean specifically using only straightedge and compass?

Comment: yes with only compass and straight edge

Comment: Given any two points $X,Y$, the locus $OX : OY = $ constant is a circle (or line). It is not hard to construct it by compass and straight edge. You essentially require to construct two circles and find their intersection. The point you want is constructible (if exists and I believe it does but I don't have a proof ;-p)

Comment: Built on the above comment, if you construct the intersection of circle $O_1$ of constant $AC:BC$ ratio between $A,B$, and circle $O_2$ of constant $BA:CA$ ratio between $B, C$, then $AO:BO=AC:BC$ and $BO:CO=BA:CA$ and by simple multiplication $CO:AO$ is automatically $CB:AB$ and existence is proven.

Comment: By "$AO\times BC$", do you mean the product of the lengths of the segments $\overline{AO}$ and $\overline{BC}$? Or do you mean the *cross product* of the vectors $\overrightarrow{AO}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$?

Comment: not cross product of vectors. just the product of length segments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These points are known
in [ETC](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X15)
as 1st and 2nd isodynamic points,
the triangle centers $X_{15}$ and $X_{16}$.

[Isodynamic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isodynamic_point):

> In Euclidean geometry, the isodynamic points of a triangle are points
> associated with the triangle, with the properties that  ... the
> distances from the isodynamic point to the triangle vertices are
> inversely proportional to the opposite side lengths of the triangle.

The barycentric coordinates of these points are

\begin{align} 
X_{15}:\quad&
a\sin(\alpha + \tfrac\pi3) &: b\sin(\beta + \tfrac\pi3) : c \sin(\gamma + \tfrac\pi3)
,\\
X_{16}:\quad&
a\sin(\alpha - \tfrac\pi3) &: b\sin(\beta - \tfrac\pi3) : c \sin(\gamma - \tfrac\pi3)
.
\end{align}

As a linear combination of the vertices,

\begin{align} 
X_{15}&=\frac{u\cdot A+v\cdot B+w\cdot C}{u+v+w}
,\\
u&=a\sin(\alpha + \tfrac\pi3)
,\\
v&=b\sin(\beta + \tfrac\pi3)
,\\
w&=c \sin(\gamma + \tfrac\pi3)
, 
\end{align}
and the invariants are

\begin{align} 
a\cdot |AX_{15}|&=b\cdot |BX_{15}|=c\cdot |CX_{15}|
\\
&=
\frac{\sqrt2\,abc}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+4\sqrt3 S}}
,\\
a\cdot |AX_{16}|&=b\cdot |BX_{16}|=c\cdot |CX_{16}|
\\
&=
\frac{\sqrt2\,abc}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2-4\sqrt3 S}}
,
\end{align}

where $S$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Example: for the the nominal $6-9-13$ triangle,

\begin{align} 
a&=6,\quad b=9,\quad c=13,\quad S=4\sqrt{35}
,\\
a\cdot |AX_{15}|&=b\cdot |BX_{15}|=c\cdot |CX_{15}|
=\frac{702 \sqrt2}{\sqrt{286+16\sqrt{105}}}
\approx 46.80
,\\
a\cdot |AX_{16}|&=b\cdot |BX_{16}|=c\cdot |CX_{16}|
=\frac{702 \sqrt2}{\sqrt{286-16\sqrt{105}}}
\approx 89.86
.
\end{align}

Construction.

[image]

Points $A_b.A_e$ and $B_b,B_e$
are the feet of the internal and external bisectors
of the angles $CAB=\alpha$
and $ABC=\beta$, respectively.
Points
$O_a=\tfrac12(A_b+A_e)$,
$O_b=\tfrac12(B_b+B_e)$
are the centers of the circles
$\mathcal{C_a}$ and $\mathcal{C_b}$
through points
$A,A_b,A_e$
and $B,B_b,B_e$, respectively.
Intersection of the circles
$\mathcal{C_a}$ and $\mathcal{C_b}$
gives the pair of isodynamic points,
1st, $X_{15}$ inside $\triangle ABC$
and 2nd, $X_{16}$, outside of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: just now i realized that these points are the isogonal conjugate of fermat point

Comment: @endgame endgame: yes, and [a lot of other properties](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X15).

Answer (score 2):

$\color{blue}{\text{Due to a nonstandard usage in the question,}}$

$\color{blue}{\text{it was assumed that the multiplication symbol referred to a vector cross product,}}$

$\color{blue}{\text{and this answer was constructed accordingly.}}$

$\color{blue}{\text{It would not apply if the multiplication is a product of lengths.}}$

Yes, provided you watch your signs.  You have to render the second cross product as $BO×\color{blue}{CA}$.

Let $O$ be the interior point.  Then $|AO×BC|$ measures twice the sum of $|\triangle AOB|$ and $|\triangle AOC|$ and the vector is directed into the region of space from which $A,B,C$ appear to be in clockwise order.  Cyclic permutations of this apply for $BO×CA$ and $CO×AB$.  Then the cross products $AO×BC,BO×CA,CO×AB$ are all identical by making the areas of the smaller triangles equal, which means $O$ is the centroid.

Comment: $BO\times AC$ means merely the product of the lengths of the segments, accordin to the comments above. So there is no sign to mind. Also, the result of that product is not the area of the parallelogram spanned by $BO$ and $AC$; it is independent of the angle between them.

Comment: The multiplication symbol appears to me as vector cross product.  I act accordingly.  Please use proper symbolism to clarify.